# count views for anonymous users in django

Tags: django

I am creating a blog just for practice and i recently added the views counter function the problem is when an anonymous user open the post django raise an error because in the post_detail view i request the username this is the view:

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    if UserSeenPosts.objects.filter(post=post, user=request.user).exists():
        print "all ready"
    else:
        post.views += 1
        post.save()
        UserSeenPosts.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'Post': Post.objects.get(id=post_id)})
```

the UserSeenPosts model:

```
class UserSeenPosts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='seen_posts')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

So can django give anonymous users names like guest1 / guest2 and this should be serialized to avoid duplicated names

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if user is authenticated.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    UserSeenPosts.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
```

Comment: i know but this wont count the view

Comment: If the user is not logged in, you cannot call. UserSeenPosts.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post) if you don't mind whether logged in or not do: UserSeenPosts.objects.create(user=None, post=post). and make the field user nullable in the model.

Comment: thanks for your response but can you see the updated question : )

Comment: If you just want to map all anonymous users to one object. You can create an object for all the anonymous one. Call it 'Guest 1'. Then do the checking for the user is logged in or not and call the appropriate object ?

Comment: thank you i hate this project not working for me thank you : )